# YAML error when using FOSUserBundle with Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

I'm running in to a weird error when setting up FOSUserBundle in Symfony.
I get this error message:

```
A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 30 (near " csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager").
```

Here is my security.yml, can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
#        in_memory:
#            memory: ~
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I have tried commenting out the line that's mentioned in the error message (csrf_token_generator) but the error persists, now pointing to the line above it.

Comment: try quote the value "security.csrf.token_manager" =>  csrf_token_generator: "security.csrf.token_manager"

Comment: I have tried that, it made no difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think It's a problem of indentation,

try to change this:

```
pattern: ^/
    form_login:
         provider: fos_userbundle
         csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

    logout:       true
    anonymous:    true
```

to this:

```
pattern: ^/
form_login:
    provider: fos_userbundle
    csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

logout:       true
anonymous:    true
```

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri please format code properly. Thanks :)